# Magento transactional email new order email template product image missing

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates

In my store am using transactional email new order template for get notification.
All Are working good. But in order email product `image` is missing how can i solve this error.

This is error:
[image]

transactional email **new order** code:

```
    <body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;color:#000;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;color:#000;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
            <!-- [ header starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td  align="center" valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <h1 style="font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0; color:#ff2dff;">YOUR ORDER CONFIRMATION</h1>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
                        <b>Thank you for shopping with us, {{htmlescape var=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}!</b> <br /><br />
</p>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:26px; margin:0;">
                        We wanted to let you know that: <br />
                         • Your order (Order no: {{var order.increment_id}}) was received, and is in process. <br />
                         {{block type="core/template" template="email/order/example.phtml" order=$order}}
                         • We’ll follow up with another e-mail once your package is on its way. <br />
In the meantime, all the details are below, and you can check your  <br />
order status online anytime.<br />
You can check the status of your order by <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">logging into your account</a>. 
<p style="color:#ff2dff; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#ff2dff;">The MW Team is Here to Help</p>
<p>If you have any questions regarding your order or would like to make changes, please feel free to email us on <a href="mailto:contactus@abc.in" style="color:#1E7EC8;">contactus@abc.in</a> or call us on +91 9008423121 Monday-Saturday 10 AM - 6 PM IST
                    </p>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Billing Information:</th>
                            <th width="10"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Payment Method:</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var payment_html}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Shipping Information:</th>
                            <th width="10"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Shipping Method:</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{/depend}}
                    {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
                    <p style="font-size:12px; margin:0 0 10px 0">{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="2" align="center" style="background:#ffffff; text-align:center; padding-bottom:0px;">
<div class="homearrow_right" style="height: 15px; float:left; width: 100%;background:#EAEAEA;">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div style=" margin:0 auto; margin-top:-5px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/abcjewellery?ref=hl" target="_blank"><img src="https://abc.in/skin/frontend/coolbaby/default/images/fb-icon.png"></a>
<a href="http://www.pinterest.com/abc/" target="_blank"><img src="https://abc.in/skin/frontend/coolbaby/default/images/instagram.png"></a><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/abc/" target="_blank"><img src="https://abc.in/skin/frontend/coolbaby/default/images/pinterest.png"></a>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" style="background:#FFFFFF; padding-top:0px; text-align:left;"><p style="font-size:10px; margin:0;">If you are not the intended recipient or have received this email in error, please delete immediately. 
Any dissemination, distribution, or copying of this message by any person other than the intended recipient is strictly prohibited.
</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think this is the error line `{{/depend}}   {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

Comment: Can any one help in this...?